# Finding the nth term of a series

Tags: sequences

Find the n'th term of DJ(i).

Given DJ(i) is the number of times i is present in DJ(i)

The array DJ(i) is as shown:

```
   i       1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ..... 
DJ(i)      1 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 5  5 .....
```

I want the nth term of the series DJ(i). I have to carry out some further calculations with the term.

Comment: I don't get this part >"Given DJ(i) is the number of times i is present in DJ(i)" or maybe the example isn't complete ?

Comment: It is complete....actually DJ(1)=1 and DJ(2)=2

Comment: DJ(i) = number of times i is present in DJ(i) => this doesn't make sense ! it's like you're telling me Y = number*i present in Y ?_? For example Y = DJ(8) = 1 because "8" is present only once in Y ... Or am i missing something ?

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV after the index 2, the definition is very correct.

Comment: Would you then please explain why DJ(1)=(1), DJ(2)=2, DJ(3)=2, DJ(4)=3, DJ(5)=3,DJ(6)=4 ... If i don't understand the logic behind it, how can i help you then?

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV See number of times 2 appears is 2. Therefore DJ(3)=2, now since DJ(i) has to be a monotonic sequence, the result follows. Now we have DJ(3)=2, it implies that 3 is present twice in the list. Therefore DJ(4)=3 and DJ(5)=3....and so on..could you get the logic?

Comment: @AakashAnuj the logic is still unclear. Post more of the series

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV refer to the post below (the table) for the series

Comment: @AakashAnuj after knowing the sequence name, i searched on the net, and i got the idea thx ! I think you may compute the terms until nth term. Which programming language are you using ?

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV I am using C. Computation is easy. The only thing that remains is finding the n'th term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up the value in this [table](http://oeis.org/A001462/b001462.txt) or compute yourself the table in the programming language of your choice (left as an easy exercise). Also check this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786087/golombs-sequence) and [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A001462).